# Delphi Error : Equals.Caption := ; Expression expected but ';' found

Tags: delphi

I followed this: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Simple_Calculator_Tutorial

This is my code in Delphi:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Addition: TButton;
    Subtraction: TButton;
    Multiplication: TButton;
    Division: TButton;
    One: TButton;
    Two: TButton;
    Three: TButton;
    Four: TButton;
    Five: TButton;
    Six: TButton;
    Seven: TButton;
    Eight: TButton;
    Nine: TButton;
    Zero: TButton;
    Decimal: TButton;
    Enter: TButton;
    ClearValue: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Negative: TButton;
    Reset: TButton;
    NumberEdit: TEdit;
    Equals: TLabel;
    procedure NegativeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AdditionClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SubtractionClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MultiplicationClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DivisionClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EnterClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ClearValueClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ResetClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure NumberEditChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure NumberButtonClick (Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

var
  FNumber : real;
  Math : string;    

procedure TForm3.NumberButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NumberEdit.Text := NumberEdit.Text + (Sender as TButton).Caption;
end;    

procedure TForm3.NegativeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OriginalNumber: real;
  TextNumber: string;
begin
  OriginalNumber := -(StrToFloat(NumberEdit.Text));
  TextNumber := FormatFloat('0.##########', OriginalNumber);
  NumberEdit.Text := TextNumber
end;    

procedure TForm3.AdditionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Math := 'Add';
  FNumber := StrToFloat(NumberEdit.Text);
  NumberEdit.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm3.SubtractionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Math := 'Subtract';
  FNumber := StrToFloat(NumberEdit.Text);
  NumberEdit.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm3.MultiplicationClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Math := 'Multiply';
  FNumber := StrToFloat(NumberEdit.Text);
  NumberEdit.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm3.DivisionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Math := 'Divide';
  FNumber := StrToFloat(NumberEdit.Text);
  NumberEdit.Clear;
end;    

procedure TForm3.EnterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Answer, SNumber : real;
  Text : string;    
begin
  SNumber := StrToFloat(NumberEdit.Text);    
  begin
    if Math = 'Add' then
      Answer := FNumber + SNumber;
    Text := FormatFloat('0.#####', Answer);
    Equals.Caption := '= ' + Text;
    NumberEdit.Clear;
  end;

  begin
    if Math = 'Subtract' then
      Answer := FNumber - SNumber;
    Text := FormatFloat('0.#####', Answer);
    Equals.Caption := '= ' + Text;
    NumberEdit.Clear;
  end;

  begin
    if Math = 'Multiply' then
      Answer := FNumber * SNumber;
    Text := FormatFloat('0.#####', Answer);
    Equals.Caption := '= ' + Text;
    NumberEdit.Clear;
  end;

  begin
    if Math = 'Divide' then
      Answer := FNumber / SNumber;
    Text := FormatFloat('0.#####', Answer);
    Equals.Caption := '= ' + Text;
    NumberEdit.Clear;    
  end;

end;

procedure TForm3.ClearValueClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NumberEdit.Clear;
end;   

procedure TForm3.ResetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Equals.Caption := ;
  NumberEdit.Clear;
  FNumber := 0;
  SNumber := 0;
  Math := 'Default';
end;

end.
```

This is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[image: This Screenshot Errors]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. Just mark (for instance with a comment like `// <-- here is the error`), in the code, where the error occurs.

Comment: Or better yet, right-click in the Messages window and choose *Copy* from the menu, and then paste it into your post here as text. Images should only be used when there is no other way to illustrate the problem, and that isn't the case here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error line says it all: it expects an expression but it finds a semicolon.

This line:

```
Equals.Caption := ;
```

is not a valid statement. You must assign a string (an *expression* resulting in a string, which can just as well be only a string literal) to the `Caption`. It can be an empty string, `''`, e.g.

```
Equals.Caption := '';
```

---

*I see that the original code you used has this error too. Well, seems to be a typo, probably occurred when they marked the code with highlighting HTML tags like `<b>` and `<i>`.*